# почему последний alert(i) выводит 3, а не 2 (как последнее значение)? Как вообще цикл возвращает значение?

Tags: javascript, циклы, for

```js
let i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // используем существующую переменную
  alert(i); // 0, 1, 2
}

alert(i); // 3, переменная доступна, т.к. была объявлена снаружи цикла
```

Answer (score 4):

циклы `for` выглядят так:

```
i = 0;

cycle:

    тело цикла

    i ++;

    if условие
        goto cycle;
```

циклы `while` выглядят так:

```
cycle:

    if not(условие):
        goto end;

    тело цикла

    goto cycle;

end:
```

циклы `do while` (там где они есть) выглядят так:

```
cycle:
   
    тело цикла

    if условие:
        goto end;

    goto cycle;

end:
```

Так что в вашем случае было так:

```
i = 0;

cycle:

тело цикла

i ++;

if (i < 3)
    goto cycle;
```

так что на выходе получается i = 3

Answer (score 3):

Потому что после каждой итерации `i` увеличивается на единицу. После (не внутри) третьей итерации `i` равно `3`. Перед четвертой итерацией происходит проверка условия `i < 3`, и цикл прерывается.

Comment: Спасибо, бро! После ответа все стало очевидным.

Comment: @ПавелКолесник Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.